# Android finish all previous activities

Tags: android-intent, stack, activity-finish

I have got the series of activities as follows , named as A, B, C, D for instance

At C , I will start the services Until F

at F, I will stop the recording service and submit the data and voice file to the server by Async Task

A -> B -> C -> D - > E -> F -> B -> C -> D -> E

At F , I shall finish the activity in this way :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } ...
....

    Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);    
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                startActivity(new Intent(F.this , B.class)
.putExtra("salesid" , userid).putExtra("orderid" ,orderid ));           
                parent.finish();
                System.exit(0);
```

For others, just use :

```
startActivity(new Intent("this Activity".this , "next Activity".class)
```

At B , I have logout and exit buttons to finish the Activity by

```
   startActivity(new Intent(B.this , A.class)
                finish();
```

At A, I have

```
    System.exit(0);
```

The question is , when I back to A ,

A -> B -> C -> D - > E -> F -> B -> A

and press exit ,

The Activity stack goes like this

A -> B -> C -> D - > E

Would you please tell me how to delete all these previous activity stack ?